# ¿Cómo saltar a la siguiente iteracion de un FOR mediante exception PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle-10g

Estoy realizado un ciclo for en Oracle 10g, dentro del ciclo tengo una consulta, lo que necesito es que si esta consulta no retorna nada o da error salte a la siguiente iteracion sin realizar las siguientes instrucciones.

```
      FOR I IN LTRN.FIRST .. LTRN.COUNT

        LOOP


    SELECT ID_CLIENTE

     INTO VID_CLIENT`introducir el código aquí`E

          FROM AAA_CLIENTES

              WHERE ID_PERSONA = LTRN(I).ID_PERSONA;

                    LTRN(I).ID_CLIENTE := VID_CLIENTE;

/*(Aquí debería ir el "exception" y dentro de este la opción para saltar a la siguiente iteracion del for, intente con Go To pero me generar error)*/


      END LOOP;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Según veo [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/q/177752/1065197) puedes simular eso con una sentencia `GOTO`. En Oracle 11g recién se agregó la sentencia `CONTINUE`.

Comment: Intente poner después de Exception when other el Go To pero me genera error al compilar.

Comment: y porque no pones un If? IF (esta todo bien) /**instrucciones**/ endif. y asi no realizaría las instrucciones y llegaría al final del bucle para comenzar de nuevo

Comment: Seria una alternativa, pero creí que se podía simular el continue del oracle 11g de alguna forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencione en los comentarios, se podría usar un bloque IF ENDIF.

```
 FOR I IN LTRN.FIRST .. LTRN.COUNT
   LOOP

    BEGIN
    SELECT ID_CLIENTE

     INTO VID_CLIENT`introducir el código aquí`E

          FROM AAA_CLIENTES

              WHERE ID_PERSONA = LTRN(I).ID_PERSONA;

                    LTRN(I).ID_CLIENTE := VID_CLIENTE;
           IF NOExisteExeption THEN
               /*Instrucciones a realizar cuando no existe ninguna exeption
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .*/
         ENDIF;
      END;
/**continua el bucle**/
END LOOP;
```